# USB does not work on elementary OS (Juno) on virtual box

Tags: system, usb-drive

I have decided to install Juno. As it is new I thought to try it without installing it on my computer, i will have to backup lots of data so I thought lets see it at once. I installed it in virtual box. I just notice that my pen drive is not working. But we have this old one that works fine. Can anyone tell me whats hap penning here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think there's nothing wrong with elementary OS, the problem is with your Virtual Box instead. I am guessing your USB (not supported one) is USB 3 and the other one (old one) is USB 2. And you may don't have [virtual box extension pack](https://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/6.0.0/Oracle_VM_VirtualBox_Extension_Pack-6.0.0.vbox-extpack) installed.
What is abnormal to me is, you are supposed to get some error if you haven't installed that when you created the machine. Let me know the results.

Comment: I followed an article to create the machine, which instructed me to select usb 2 from the usb settings. I am going to install the extension pack and will let you know.

Comment: Installing extension pack did the work.